# What may cause resource.h to have negative values defined for MFC controls?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, mfc

Currently, we have `#define IDC_*` added to the point that we have reached 32767 (0x7FFF).

Now that we tried to add 32768 (0x8000), all the sudden it became a negative value (`#define IDC_TEST_BUTTON -32768` which is also 0x8000). From there on, `#define` statements are incrementing starting from -32768 (such as -32767, -32766, etc).

Our `_APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE` is pointing to 32769, as it should be.

I thought maybe this is a bug with Microsoft's use of `unsigned short` and `signed short`, so I created a new MFC project and intentionally set the `_APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE` to 32768 and started adding controls in the designer. However, in this case, `#define IDC_TEST_BUTTON 32768` and `_APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE` became 32769, as expected.

I searched my entire program's `resource.h` to see if there are any possible duplicate numbers, since that seems to cause `#define` statements to become negative. But I could not find any.

According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn020-id-naming-and-numbering-conventions?view=vs-2019), IDC is allowed up to the value of 0xDFFF, so 0x8000 is well within the allowed ID.

Does anybody have any clue why this is happening?

Comment: Please add a tag to indicate the version of Visual Studio you are using.

Comment: @IInspectable added!